# TableView autorefresh

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, refresh, scenebuilder

I am working on an JavaFx project and am facing a problem.

So there is my `Controller` class :

```
package ArticleGUI;

import Entities.Article;
import Gestion.GestionArticle;
import com.sun.prism.impl.Disposer.Record;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListeArticleFXMLController extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableView<Article> tabArt;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Article, Integer> refCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Article, Hyperlink> titreCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Article, String> descCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Article, String> contCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Article, String> medCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn supCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn modifCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn affichCol;
    @FXML
    private Button reload;


    GestionArticle ga = new GestionArticle();
    ArrayList<Article> listA = (ArrayList<Article>) ga.afficherArticle();
    public ObservableList<Article> articleData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listA);



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        tabArt.setItems(articleData);

        refCol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Article,Integer>("Reference"));

        titreCol.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Article,Hyperlink>("Nom"));

        descCol.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Article,String>("Description"));

        contCol.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Article,String>("Contenu"));

        medCol.setCellValueFactory(
                   new PropertyValueFactory<Article,String>("IdMed"));


        supCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });

        supCol.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new DelButton();
            }

        });


        modifCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });

        modifCol.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new ModifButton();
            }

        });

        affichCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });

        affichCol.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new AffichButton();
            }

        });

    }

    public void refresh(){
        articleData.clear();
        List<Article> la=new ArrayList<>();
        la=ga.afficherArticle();
        articleData.setAll(la);
        tabArt.setItems(articleData);
    }

    public void setTabArt(TableView<Article> tabArt) {
        this.tabArt = tabArt;
    }

    public TableColumn<Article, Integer> getRefCol() {
        return refCol;
    }

    public void setRefCol(TableColumn<Article, Integer> refCol) {
        this.refCol = refCol;
    }

    public TableColumn<Article, Hyperlink> getTitreCol() {
        return titreCol;
    }

    public void setTitreCol(TableColumn<Article, Hyperlink> titreCol) {
        this.titreCol = titreCol;
    }

    public TableColumn<Article, String> getDescCol() {
        return descCol;
    }

    public void setDescCol(TableColumn<Article, String> descCol) {
        this.descCol = descCol;
    }

    public TableColumn<Article, String> getContCol() {
        return contCol;
    }

    public void setContCol(TableColumn<Article, String> contCol) {
        this.contCol = contCol;
    }

    public TableColumn<Article, String> getMedCol() {
        return medCol;
    }

    public void setMedCol(TableColumn<Article, String> medCol) {
        this.medCol = medCol;
    }

    public ObservableList<Article> getArticleData() {
        return articleData;
    }



}
```

And there is my `Button` class :

```
package ArticleGUI;

import Entities.Article;
import Gestion.GestionArticle;
import com.sun.prism.impl.Disposer.Record;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class DelButton extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {

    ListeArticleFXMLController l = new ListeArticleFXMLController();
    final Button supp = new Button("Supprimer");

    public DelButton() {
        supp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                GestionArticle ga = new GestionArticle();
                try {
                    Article currentArt = (Article) DelButton.this.getTableView().getItems().get(DelButton.this.getIndex());
                    Alert a1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                    a1.setTitle("Suppresion Article");
                    a1.setHeaderText(null);
                    a1.setContentText("Etes vous vraiment sur de vouloir supprimer " + currentArt.getNom() + " ?\n");
                    Optional<ButtonType> button = a1.showAndWait();
                    if (button.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                        l.getArticleData().remove(currentArt);
                        ga.supprimerArticle(currentArt);
                        l.refresh();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }            
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setGraphic(supp);
        }
    }


}
```

and [this is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv1E3.png) (supprimer=delete) :

So i want my TableView to refresh automatically when I delete an article. Is there anyone who could help me?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First, your table cell implementation doesn't properly handle the case where the cell is empty. Consequently, if a cell that was not empty becomes empty (which is exactly the case when you delete items from the backing list), the cell is not updated properly; it continues to show the value of the item that the cell previously represented.

The correct implementation is

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(t, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(supp);
    }
}
```

And second, you need to communicate with the actual controller, or otherwise delete the item from the table's actual backing list. You are currently creating an object and removing an item from a list that object contains:

```
ListeArticleFXMLController l = new ListeArticleFXMLController();
// ...
l.getArticleData().remove(currentArt);
```

The easiest way is to pass the list to the cell implementation:

```
public class DelButton extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {


    final Button supp = new Button("Supprimer");

    public DelButton(ObservableList<Article> articleList) {

        supp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                GestionArticle ga = new GestionArticle();
                try {
                    Article currentArt = (Article) DelButton.this.getTableView().getItems().get(DelButton.this.getIndex());
                    Alert a1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                    a1.setTitle("Suppresion Article");
                    a1.setHeaderText(null);
                    a1.setContentText("Etes vous vraiment sur de vouloir supprimer " + currentArt.getNom() + " ?\n");
                    Optional<ButtonType> button = a1.showAndWait();
                    if (button.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                        articleList.remove(currentArt);
                        ga.supprimerArticle(currentArt);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }            
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(supp);
        }
    }


}
```

and then

```
    supCol.setCellFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
            return new DelButton(articleData);
        }

    });
```

Comment: The first thing I have to say is "sorry". It's been 10 hours that I work and I start to be more and more dizzy. Thank you for help it was very useful to me.